# How to use Spring Boot with MySQL database and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I want to setting Spring Boot with MySQL and JPA. For this I create:
**Person**

```
package domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String firstName;

// setters and getters
}
```

**PersonRepository**

```
package repository;

import domain.Person;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**PersonController**

```
package controller;

import domain.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import repository.PersonRepository;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String test() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("First");
    person.setLastName("Test");
    personRepository.save(person);
    return "hello";
}
}
```

Start class **Example**:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
}

}
```

And for database configuration, I create **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_spring_boot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

So I have project structure:

[image]

But as a result I have exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Example]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

As a example I use:  [spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/pom.xml)

Comment: What's that link supposed to tell us? It's the pom.xml for the 1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of Spring Boot Data JPA sample. Also, how are you running the application?

Comment: @Steve, I run my Example.java in IDE IDEA

Comment: Does it run from the command line?

Comment: Not an answer. But, if you are facing an issue you might be using deprecated driver-class-name. Use `spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cf.jdbc.Driver` instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I created a project like you did. The structure looks like this

[image: project structure]

The Classes are just copy pasted from yours.

I changed the **application.properties** to this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testproject
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But I think your problem is in your **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>spring-boot-sample-jpa</artifactId>
<name>Spring Boot JPA Sample</name>
<description>Spring Boot JPA Sample</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Check these files for differences. Hope this helps

**Update 1:** I changed my username. The link to the example is now https://github.com/Yannic92/stackOverflowExamples/tree/master/SpringBoot/MySQL

Comment: I copy your changes. It's very sad, but I have exception yet `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: Then you have more in your project than you showed to us. Your Problem has something to do with spring security. Do you still have spring security in your maven dependencies?

Comment: No, I haven't. I show all my architecture and classes.

Comment: Wait a sec. I'll upload my project to GitHub so you can get it from there. It should be exactly the same project as yours and it works.

Comment: Your code really works! And I cann't find different between your project and my. By anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When moving classes into specific packages like repository, controller, domain just the generic `@SpringBootApplication` is not enough.

You will have to specify the base package for component scan

```
@ComponentScan("base_package")
```

For JPA

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
```

is also needed, so spring data will know where to look into for repository interfaces.

Comment: Mh yes and no. If you use `@SpringBootApplication` all your components have to be at the same level or lower than the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. In this example this is the case so no `@ComponentScan` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Please add **mysql-connector-java** dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and Add the below mentioned properties in **application.properties**

```
# Data Source properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=YourPassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA properties 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 2):

For Jpa based application: base package scan
***@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")***
You can try it once!!!
**Project Structure**

```
com
 +- stack
     +- app
     |   +- Application.java
     +- controller
     |   +- EmployeeController.java
     +- service
     |   +- EmployeeService.java
     +- repository
     |   +- EmployeeRepository.java
     +- model
     |   +- Employee.java
-pom.xml
dependencies: 
    mysql, lombok, data-jpa
```

**application.properties**

```
#Data source :
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Jpa/Hibernate :
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "employee")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column (name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column (name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column (name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column (name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column (name = "emp_desg")
    private String desgination;
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;

    @GetMapping (value = "/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
        return empService.getAllEmployees();
    }

    @PostMapping (value = "/employee")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmp(@RequestBody Employee emp, HttpServletRequest 
                                         request) throws URISyntaxException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(new URI(request.getRequestURI() + "/" + emp.getId()));
        empService.saveEmployee(emp);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(emp, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**EmployeeService.java**

```
public interface EmployeeService {
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee emp);
}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return empRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee emp) {
        return empRepository.save(emp);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
public class EmployeeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [spring boot reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html),it said:

> When a class doesn’t include a package declaration it is considered to be in the “default package”. The use of the “default package” is generally discouraged, and should be avoided. It can cause particular problems for Spring Boot applications that use @ComponentScan, @EntityScan or @SpringBootApplication annotations, since every class from every jar, will be read.

```
com
 +- example
     +- myproject
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- domain
         |   +- Customer.java
         |   +- CustomerRepository.java
         |
         +- service
         |   +- CustomerService.java
         |
         +- web
             +- CustomerController.java
```

In your cases. You must add `scanBasePackages` in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.just like`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"domain","contorller"..})`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in the default package, i.e. you have source all files in src/main/java with no custom package. I strongly suggest u to create package n then place your source file in it.

```
Ex-
 src->
     main->
          java->
                com.myfirst.example
                   Example.java
                com.myfirst.example.controller
                   PersonController.java
                com.myfirst.example.repository
                  PersonRepository.java
                com.myfirst.example.model
                   Person.java
```

I hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score -10):

You can move `Application.java` to a folder under the java.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10777423)

Comment: I try to run the application and get the same Exception, after move the main class to a folder,The app can run success.