# spring boot data jpa mysql could not create database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new in spring 
I will post my code,
that the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and this my entity

```
    package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private String phone;
private String adresse;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}
public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}
public Person(long id, String name, String phone, String adresse) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.adresse = adresse;
}
public Person() {
    super();
}

}
```

and this is the repository

```
package repositry;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import model.Person;

public interface PersonRespositry extends  JpaRepository<Person, Long>  {


}
```

and my controller

```
   package contoller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import model.Person;

import repositry.PersonRespositry;

@RestController
public class PersonController {

    PersonRespositry rp;
    @Autowired
    public  PersonController(PersonRespositry rp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.rp=rp;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/find")
    public Person find(long id){
        return rp.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findall")
    public List<Person> findall(){
        return rp.findAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public String Demo(){
        return "Hello world !!";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String create(){
        Person p=new Person();
        p.setName("med");
        p.setPhone("233888");
        p.setAdresse("rue ");
        rp.save(p);
        return " success";
    }


}
```

This is the architect of the project:

[image]

When I run the application the database does not generate and only the 
localhost:8080 is running.

Comment: you have to first create the schema(database) manually. Then run the app and app should create the tables in schema

Comment: i create the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the location of the `Application.java`.

`@ComponentScan`looks for Spring beans inside the package of the class annotated with (`@SpringBootApplication` contains `@ComponentScan`) and in subpackages of this package.

I already provided an example to a very similar setup.

Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983870/2576531

Furthermore the hint of Robert Moskal is correct. The database itself has to exist already. Only the tables will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be created you need to use **create** or **create-drop**. If you are using something like mysql you'll need to have created at least the database. The tables will be created for you.

I be very careful about doing this against a production database instance.

Comment: be sure that  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update it's create or update the database

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise for me it dosen't work with @componentScan but it works now with @EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.jwt.entites" }) in the main class to scan entity classes ..

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but this is a sample. I think this will help you

```
//Pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wisdom.spring.myjdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_boot_jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring_boot_jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


//application Config

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/wisdom
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=8855
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
server.port = 8585



package com.wisdom.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.wisdom.spring.model.students;
import com.wisdom.spring.repo.students_repo;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class studentController {
    @Autowired
    students_repo STDRepo;

    @GetMapping(value = "/a")
    public String a() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/save")
    public List<students> getStudents(){

        System.out.println("Data returned");
        return STDRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/savestd")
    public void saveBurger(students student) {
        STDRepo.save(student);
    }

}


package com.wisdom.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class students {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int s_id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

    public students() {

    }

    public students(int s_id, String name, String address) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }

    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}




package com.wisdom.spring.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.wisdom.spring.model.students;

public interface students_repo extends JpaRepository<students,String> {

}




package com.wisdom.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```