# How to create a simple CRUD application using Spring Data JPA and MYSQas DB using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a simple dummy application using Spring Boot Version 1.4.4. 
Here is how my `pom.xml` looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.bootstrap</groupId>
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tsqln</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My application class looks like:

```
package com.bootstrap;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TsqlnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TsqlnApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my application.properties looks like :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lostandfound
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

But when I run the application I get the following error stating :

```
*****************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
Action:
Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
2017-01-29 17:32:44.645 ERROR 4316 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@516be40f] to prepare test instance [com.bootstrap.TsqlnApplicationTests@9573b3b]**
```

My directory structure for project is :

[image]

However with the same approach the above application works with SpringBoot version 1.3. Any suggestions how to make it work with version 1.4.4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Spring Boot with MySQL database and JPA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981789/how-to-use-spring-boot-with-mysql-database-and-jpa)

Comment: The reason for my exception is different than the above mentioned question

Comment: Nevertheless you should be able to solve your problem with the given answer. Maciej Kowalski already provided an answer that should solve your problem, too.

Comment: I tried it didn't worked same error.

Comment: I cloned a demo project from this repo [link](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web). The maven run command is executed successfully how ever when I try to run it as a springBoot application I get the same error.

Comment: What do you mean with. Run it as spring Boot application? Run it inside Eclipse or execute the built jar? Maybe its an issue with eclipse

Comment: Yes. I'm using STS and using it's run as option.

Comment: I can't help you since i dont use sts. But i suggest you add this Detail to your question and adapt the title to something that hints into direction of STS

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mysql-connector is actually there in the classpath at runtime (if your using Tomcat, then it should be in the lib folder).

If you do not have it there add a compile dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you forgot about this line in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

in your application.properties add this lines

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restore that behaviour by creating your own datasource bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username("")
        .password("")
        .url("")
        .driverClassName("")
        .build();
}
```